# ggplot same variable from different dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 different dataset (from a longitudinal study), v1, v2 and v3. Each of them has a variable of "gender".

I'd like to plot the count of each gender from each dataset in same graph (indicated by point and connected by line), i.e. x axis will be "v1", "v2" and "v3",  y axis will be the count by gender.

I know I can manually create a dataset including the values I need, but I'm wondering if there is a better way? Thank you!

The sample datasets:

```
a <- c("boy", "girl")
v1 <- data.frame(gender=rep(a, times=c(11,9)))
v2 <- data.frame(gender=rep(a, times=c(8,8)))
v3 <- data.frame(gender=rep(a, times=c(6,4)))
```

Comment: I think you'll probably have to do the data manipulation yourself. If you give a short [mcve] I could take a whack at it.

Comment: Because there are three dataset, I think it's a bit complicated to make a reproducible sample. But I can make three fake datasets. I added the code

Comment: ;) I mean, you *could* have added a variable `gender` to the mre data ;)

Comment: I have. Sorry I don't know how to make my question more clear, I think it's about I don't have time variable in my dataset. But I tried to plot the count of genders according to time. What I did is to make a subdata in long format. But I'm wondering if I can just grab the variables from different dataset to make the plot (then there will be only the sex variable, while ggplot needs x and y. That's the issue)

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying your MRE a little bit to make it easier to handle (as you did it, each object was a data frame with a single column with a weird name, and the names were different across the data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize data set:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dd <- bind_rows(lst(v1, v2, v3), .id="dataset") %>%
    count(dataset, gender)
```

Plot:

```r
ggplot(dd, aes(x=dataset, y=n, colour=gender)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_line(aes(group=gender))
```

It's conceivable that you could do the `count()` step within `ggplot` in a sensible way (using `stat_count()`, which is what's used internally by `geom_bar()`), but this seems pretty straightforward. (If you did use `stat_count()` you'd probably have to repeat it for the `geom_point()` and `geom_line()` geoms ... something I keep meaning to do is to write a `geom_linespoints` that will draw *both* points and lines, with the same set of position/stats/etc.)

Comment: Thank you! The .id option helps a lot. At least this will be much easier than I use the -dplyr- and -pivot- to do a lot transformation before I'm able to plot.